# Getting a lot of errors when trying to change theme. I am using appcompat v7 action bar

Tags: android

Here is my manifest code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.calculator.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is code from styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Holo" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Holo">
</style>
</resources>
```

Above code crashes my application.

When i change my line in manifest.xml to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat
```

It works perfectly.My question is how can i derive themes from AppCompat without getting errors and how can i use them to change theme dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your theme here:

```
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.AppCompat" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat">
  </style>

  <style name="Theme.Holo" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Holo">
  </style>      
</resources>
```